# Stream decrypting video to mpmovieplayercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, encryption, streaming

I have an encrypted video which will be downloaded to ios device.. 
I would like to stream this encrypted video by decrypting it .. 
and not actually decrypting the video at once, which my client does not want to happen ..

Hence I decided to run a socket which would listen to request and decrypt data into stream which is supposed to be read by mpmovieplayercontroller and play ..

So far i'm able to run socket, decrypt data in chunks and put it to stream ..

When the socket is first communicated i first send this type of header ..

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n \
                            Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n \
                            Connection: close\r\n \
                            Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n \
                            Content-Length: filesize\r\n \
                            Content-Dispostion: inline;\r\n\r\n";
```

and on next step i start **sending the socket with decrypted data** ..

But mpmovieplayercontroller (sourcetype is set to streaming ) is not playing it, rather it waits for some content to be decrypted and throws me this error

`'AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'`

How could i possibly get this correct .. This type of system has been implemented in android and client insists for same functionality in ios also .. please suggest what could be done on this.

How would the mpmovieplayercontroller expect the data to be if its a streaming video .. ? Am i doing it properly ?

Comment: Personally I don't see the connection between the given exception and how the decryption and streams are handled

Comment: I too don't see the connection.. But This error comes only when I specify the player type as streaming  .. so there may be some connection .